# get collapsible panel using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi guys i am trying to get the collapsiblepanelextender using jquery and javascript, here is my code:

```
function ExpandCollapse()
    {
        debugger;
        var collPanel = $find("#<%=countries.ClientID %>");
}
```

on a button click i am calling this function but collPanel is always null, is what i am doing correct? If so could you please assist as to why this is comming back as null.

countries is a collapsiblepanelextender with the `runat="server"` atrribute.

Thanks in advance.\

Kind regards.

Comment: Add an ID to the collapsible panel, eg: `<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe" runat="Server" />`, and then find it with simple jQuery: `var cpanel = $('#cpe');`

Comment: countries is my id of the CollapsiblePanelExtender. I tried it without ClientId and with it. Still no luck.

Comment: the string 'countries' is the id? Like in `ID="countries"`? if so, `$('#countries');` has to work...

Comment: try removing the hash tag    $find("countries")

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $collPanel = $('#<%=countries.ClientID %>');
```

or set the cssClass attribute and target it using

```
var $collPanel = $('.classname');
```

Comment: @johnnie Show me the generated html

Answer (score 0):

if the panel's ID="cpe1" then...

```
var p = $find("cpe");
if (p != null) {
    if (p.get_Collapsed()) ... do what you want when it is collapsed
    else ... it's not collapsed.
}
```